# Two distinc response from same AWS Lambda in Api Gatway and Postman

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have this simple Lambda

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    message = {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        'body': json.dumps({ 'username': 'bob', 'id': 200 })
    }
    return message
```

I couple it with a Api Gateway

[image]

I was having dificulties to confiure permissions o I created more than one api enpoint resources.

[image]

As far as I know, both resources are identical.
However when I call them from Postman they return difent results:

/activation returns

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": "{\"username\": \"bob murrey\", \"id\": 200}"
}
```

and /myPythonLambda

```
{
    "username": "bob murrey",
    "id": 200
}
```

I can´t find any configurantion that I could change that would explaing this difference.

Comment: did you redeploy API gateway once you made the changes? changes only take effect once API gateway is (re)deployed to a stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you have done something different in API Gateway for each endpoint.

From looking at the two different responses, it appears you have ticked the Proxy integration in Method Request for the myPythonLambda endpoint.

Comment: This seems to be the case. However I couldn´t change after created. I had to delete and create a new one.